# AS3 - Zoom in image?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

=)

So, I need to be able to zoom in on my image, but I cant get it to work properly.

I've got an Image showing my content, and it get it's content from a BitmapData.

The BitmapData is full-res, which is 2880x1620, and the Image is scaling to fit my window.

*The SmoothImage is the same as Image, but with smoothing added.*

```
<me:SmoothImage id="imageFull" visible="false" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

How would I go about zooming this image when I scroll my mouse?

This is the code I have, and it does change the scaling factor. But since it's set to fit my view, nothing happens...

```
        public function videoBufferWheel(event:MouseEvent):void{
            myZoom += (event.delta/10);

            if(myZoom >=1){
                imageFull.scaleX = myZoom;
                imageFull.scaleY = myZoom;
            }else{
                myZoom = 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not scaling because a  element gets its maximum size (100%). You can increase this image only by set an attribute fillMode="clip".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried setting the fillMode to clip, but nothing happened. Is there another way I should do this, to let the Image component scale to fit the view, but scale the content of the Image when scrolling?

Comment: Thing is, when I've zoomed into the image, I need to be able to pan the image too (holding down <space> while dragging).

Comment: Are you sure that myZoom is really changed? Because I checked <s:Image> zooming. And it worked.
`<s:Image id="testImage" height="100%" width="100%" fillMode="clip"/>`

Comment: I use MX. I'll try to switch over to spark and see if that works better ;)
Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: Thanks. I can now zoom using your method. But how would I go about to pan this image? When zoomed in, I need to be able to move around.

I do have the key grabbing done, I just need to know how to actually move around :)
image.x did not work, as it just moved the image container, not the image itself (inside of it's container Image)

Comment: If you want to use `<mx:Image>` in this case set `height` and `width` in pixels, not in percents. 
About panoraming. If you talk about dragging left-right then just wrap the <s:Image> (or <mx:Image>) and move it inside the container. You can not move image inside the <s:Image> element. But if you want a real panoraming effect then you should use a 3D engine.